# Array with values changed into sql or array directly to sql in colum per index => result

Tags: php, sql, arrays, global

Well i found out how to print my global arrays, works great but now i have a problem, i want to print that array into sql

the code :

```
print_r($_SESSION['cart']);
```

returns :

```
Array ( [1] => 2 [2] => 1 [3] => 1 )
```

thats great, i know exactly what has been select, but the user wont know that...

so my question its how can i print that array in sql database but changing the index

example :

```
Array ( [1] => 2 [2] => 1 [3] => 1 )
```

for

```
Array ( [name1] => 2 [name2] => 1 [name3] => 1 )
```

based only if the index [x] exist in the current array results so in the database will look somehting like this :

```
[name1] => 2
[name2] => 1
[name3] => 1
```

and i can just call that line back, or how to print on diferent columns the same array

example :

```
from array : Array ( [1] => 2 [2] => 1 [3] => 1 )
to sql :

id    quantity
[1]     2
[2]     1
[3]     1
```

is it posible to print the array in sql in this way ? and how to do that

Ty in advance

Comment: what do you mean by "print the array in sql"?

Comment: in the database, then call the database and change the values for product names,

x = product
y = quantity

database print :
[x]y

Comment: Is this a php question?  I don't have arrays in my sql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get data from sql:

```
$id2name=array();
$x=mysql_query("SELECT id,name FROM goods WHERE id IN(".implode(',',array_keys($array)).")");
while($y=mysql_fetch_assoc($x)){
    $id2name[$y['id']]=$y['name'];
}
```

You can print this way:

```
foreach($array as $k=>$v){
    print "[".$id2name[$k]."]\t".$v."\n";
}
```

...and i want to change the index for the name. It's easy

```
foreach($array as $k=>$v)
   $new_arr[get_name($k)]=$v; //where get name = some function, that get name from id(you can get as I see in your site)
```

code for saving:

```
$str="";
foreach($array as $k=>$v){
    $str.="[".$k."]&nbsp;".$v."<br/>";
}
//now you can use $str
```

Comment: well that was a partial solution to the question xD
i modify it to :
foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $k=>$v){
    print "<br>[".$k."]\t".$v."\n<br>";
}

any ideas of how i can call that back after i print it in the sql so it returns the name of the product instead of number [x]#
?

should i make like php variables for those index's ?

[1] = "1 leg man"

print x sql bla bla where [1] = "$var"

idk i cant figure it out yet x.x

Comment: @Wesker, if I understand your question correctly, read the new version of answer

Comment: mmmmm i belive i did something wrong :

$id2name=array(); $x=mysql_query("SELECT id,name FROM products WHERE id IN(".implode(',',array_keys($_SESSION['cart'])).")"); while($y=mysql_fetch_assoc($x)){ $id2name[$y['id']]=$y['name']; }
foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $k=>$v){
    print "[".$y[$k]."]\t".$v."\n";
}


result :

[] 1 [] 1 [] 1 [] 1

Comment: is it posible to just echo "y valor if [x] on the database ?"

like database :

[1]2
[2]2
[3]2

if [1] then
echo "[product x]2"

even if i have to type them manual i belide it will be simpler

Comment: I think now I don't really understand your question. Can you explain me more?

Comment: edited. Anyway,maybe query is incorrect(return false/no any row)

Comment: check www.neobotmx.org/test/tienda.php

click on comprar a few times, on some pages to return use, ver productos.

on the right side im testing the arrays

now you can see that the php code displays :

product name , quantity , cost.

the arrays save the id of the product and the quantity, what i want its to make a billing order if you want to call it that, so i have to save the array if the users buys it, (save it in sql) and then display to the user the "order" that will return those valors (array content printed in the sql database as it is now in the left side)

Comment: and i want to change the index for the name

Comment: what should you save in database? Table name|quantity or table id|quantity or just text in some line like [name1] => 2
[name2] => 1
[name3] => 1

Comment: i want to save just, well i belive the less content in the database its the best way to go to make it fast, so ill just save those 2

[1]1

or what do you suggest, i belive your way better than me LOL, im open to any suggestion

Comment: try last code. also you can use serialize to save array as string and use unserialize to get an aaray from this string

Comment: get_name making me nuttz i belive i did that thing in like 3 minuts 3 days ago lol, and i cant do it now lol wait me a bit

Comment: i belive that something inside my code its avoiding it, anyways ty very much ill find that eventually xD